# RewriteRule не переписывает url если в папке существую файл попадающий под шаблон

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте!

При написании правил в .htaccess столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Код .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/(.*).html index.php\?arg=$1
```

RewriteRule не переписывает запрос если в корне существует файл article.php.

Если я, к примеру, переименую файл article.php в article1.php, правило начинает работать.

То есть проблема заключается в том что в корне лежит файл, попадающий под шаблон RewriteRule. Этот момент я выяснил методом научного тыка.

И здесь же странность. Под шаблон попадает только часть название файла, та что до .php.

Почему перестает работать правило?
Как можно обойти данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас точка перед расширением файла не экранирована, надо перед ней `\` ставить:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)\.html$ index.php\?arg=$1
```